# MVC 4 Autofac and Generic Repository pattern

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I am utilizing the Unit Of Work and Generic Repository pattern in my MVC 4 app. The problem I am trying to solve is creating Repository stubs for every entity in my system. In order to utilize the Autofac Ioc I am having to create a repository class and interface for every entity so that I can register it in Autofac.

app start...

```
builder.RegisterType<SchoolDetailRepository>().As<ISchoolDetailRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Repository class

```
 public class SchoolDetailRepository : RepositoryBase<SchoolDetail>, ISchoolDetailRepository
{
    public SchoolDetailRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory) : base(databaseFactory)
    {
    }
}
```

Interface

```
public interface ISchoolDetailRepository : IRepository<SchoolDetail>
{
}
```

It seems like a lot of extra work.

Is there a way to register the generic repository of Type rather than creating all these empty classes?

Then in my service class I can just have the generic type passed into the constructor via Ioc like...

```
public class SchoolService : ISchoolService
{
    private readonly IRepository<SchoolDetail> _schoolRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public SchoolService(IRepository<SchoolDetail> schoolRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this._schoolRepository = schoolRepository;
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

Container config

```
// Autofac iOC
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        // register controllers
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // register services
        builder.RegisterType<MembershipService>().As<IMembershipService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<SchoolService>().As<ISchoolService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<StudentService>().As<IStudentService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<ClassRoomService>().As<IClassRoomService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<CourseService>().As<ICourseService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<SchoolYearService>().As<ISchoolYearService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<EnrollmentService>().As<IEnrollmentService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<TeacherService>().As<ITeacherService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

        // register data infrastructure
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<DatabaseFactory>().As<IDatabaseFactory>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

        // register repositories
        builder.RegisterType<SchoolRepository>().As<ISchoolRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<TeacherRepository>().As<ITeacherRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<MembershipRepository>().As<IMembershipRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<RoleRepository>().As<IRoleRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<ProfileRepository>().As<IProfileRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<StudentRepository>().As<IStudentRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<ClassRoomRepository>().As<IClassRoomRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<CourseRepository>().As<ICourseRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<EnrollmentRepository>().As<IEnrollmentRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<SchoolYearRepository>().As<ISchoolYearRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<GradeLevelRepository>().As<IGradeLevelRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        //builder.RegisterType<SchoolDetailRepository>().As<ISchoolDetailRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RepositoryBase<SchoolDetail>)).As(typeof(IRepository<SchoolDetail>));

        // build and setup resolver
        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

the exception is coming from the above code where the expression you gave me runs..

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RepositoryBase<SchoolDetail>)).As(typeof(IRepository<SchoolDetail>));
```

RepositoryBase

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
private LearningCompactPilotContext _dataContext;
private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;
protected RepositoryBase(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
{
    DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
    _dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
}

protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
{
    get; private set;
}

protected LearningCompactPilotContext DataContext
{
    get { return _dataContext ?? (_dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
}

... more code
```

}

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need the [open generics](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OpenGenerics) feature of Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RepositoryBase<>))
   .As(typeof(IRepository<>));
```

Then you use your repositories exactly as you described:

```
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly IRepository<SomeEntity> _repository;

    public SchoolService(IRepository<SomeEntity> repository)
    {
        this._repository= repository;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do I have to do to my Entities to make this work? I am using Code First so my Entities are just plain POCOs. I get an error.. Entities.SchoolDetail is not an open generic type definition.

Comment: You don't need to entithing with your Entites. If you have a `RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T>` then you just add this line to your containerbuilder `builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RepositoryBase<>))       .As(typeof(IRepository<>));` and it should work. You don't need to do it for every entity. Can you post some more code how the actual container config looks like and from where do you get the exception?

Comment: see update.. the error occurs within the App_Start on the line that uses the RegisterGeneric

Comment: You need to exactly write like this: `builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RepositoryBase<>))   .As(typeof(IRepository<>));` note the empty `<>` and it will register your Repository for all of your entites. Then there is no need to manually create a dedicated Repositoty for your entites so you don't need to create e.g. `SchoolRepository` and `ISchoolRepository` and you can also remove the registrations.

Comment: I pasted the code for my RepositoryBase, I think it needs a tweak because now when builder.build runs i get teh following error... 
System.ArgumentException: The implementation type 'LearningCompact.Data.Infrastructure.RepositoryBase`1[T]' does not support the interface 'LearningCompact.Data.Infrastructure.IRepository`1'.

Comment: Yes your `RepositoryBase<T>` should implent your `IRepository<T>` and it cannot be `abstract` otherwise Autofac cannot create it. And if you want you can still create/keep your `ISchoolRepository` and `SchoolRepository` if you need some custom logic and you can register them as before. They will work together with your generic ones.